# Redshift: Add Row for each hour in a day

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table contains item_wise quantity at different hour of date. trying to add data for each hour(24 enteries in a day) with previous hour available quantity. For example for hour(2-10), it will be 5.

1. I created a table with hours enteries (1-24) & full join with shared table.

How can i add previous available entry. Need suggestion

```
item_id| date       | hour| quantity
101    | 2022-04-25 | 2   | 5
101    | 2022-04-25 | 10  | 13
101    | 2022-04-25 | 18  | 67
101    | 2022-04-25 | 23  | 27
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `generate_series` to generate hours number, let it be the `OUTER JOIN` base table,

Then use a correlated-subquery to get your expect `quantity` column

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT quantity 
        FROM T tt 
        WHERE t1.item_id = tt.item_id 
        AND t1.date = tt.date 
        AND t1.hour >= tt.hour
        ORDER BY tt.hour desc
        LIMIT 1) quantity
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT item_id,date,v.hour
    FROM generate_series(1,24) v(hour)
    CROSS JOIN T
) t1
ORDER BY  t1.hour
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided the table of int 1 .. 24 is `all24(hour)` you can use `lead` and `join`

```
select t.item_id, t.date, all24.hour, t.quantity
from all24
join ( 
     select *,
        lead(hour, 1, 25) over(partition by item_id, date order by hour) - 1 nxt_h
     from tbl
) t on all24.hour between t.hour and t.nxt_h
```